# Get the first appearance of each value in a hive query

Tags: hive

I have an event table, every row has:

```
event-id (primary key)
user-id
item-id
day
```

So, it's possible that and the same (item-id) appear in different days, but I need obtain the first day that appear every (item-id) and count all occurrence in this day.

For example

```
event-id  user-id   item-id    day
   1          pp      a        2015/05/01
   2          df      a        2015/05/01
   3          pp      b        2015/05/02
   3          al      a        2015/05/02
```

I want the follow result:

```
day          item-id     count
2015/05/01     a           2
2015/05/02     b           1
```

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT 
  min(day) as day,
  item_id,
  count (event_id) as count
FROM 
  events
GROUP BY
  day,
  item_id;
```

but doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT day, item_id, count(*) as cnt,
             MIN(day) OVER (PARTITION BY item_id) as minday      
      FROM events
      GROUP BY day, item_id
     ) e
WHERE day = minday;
```

Comment: MIN (day) compare dates as string, for example 2015-05-10 is less than 2015-05-5

Comment: @Dafne . . . Your date format appears to be YYYY/MM/DD, so that is not an issue.